# XOR equation with multiplication arrangment

Tags: arithmetic, boolean-algebra, binary

How can I move all the X to one side so the equation will become `x=y XOR <somthing>`...
$$\begin{align}
&2x \oplus y = x
\end{align}$$

`x` and `y` are bytes `0-255`

`2x` can't overflow `x<127`

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear what sort of thing $x$ or $y$ is supposed to be here.  Presumably $x$ is the "unknown" and $y$ is the "given", but where do they live (in an arithmetic?  in a boolean algebra?).

Answer (score 4):

I will assume we are dealing with unsigned integers in binary representation
or an boolean algebra which behave like that. i.e. algebra whose elements can be
viewed as a sequence of binary digits and multiplication by $2$ corresponds
to a shift of the binary digits to the right. i.e.

$$z = (z_0, z_1, z_2, \ldots )\quad\implies\quad 2z = ( 0, z_0, z_1, \ldots )$$

Notice $2x \oplus y = x \iff y  = x \oplus 2x$, we have
$$\begin{align}y \oplus 2y 
 &= (( x \oplus 2x ) \oplus 2(x \oplus 2x))
= (( x \oplus 2x ) \oplus (2x \oplus 4x))\\
&= ((( x \oplus 2x ) \oplus 2x ) \oplus 4x )
= (( x \oplus ( 2x \oplus 2x ) ) \oplus 4x )\\
&= (( x \oplus 0 ) \oplus 4x ) = x \oplus 4x\\
\end{align}
$$
This in turn implies
$$
\begin{align}
( y \oplus 2y ) \oplus 4y 
 &= y \oplus (2y \oplus 4y ) = y \oplus 2(y \oplus 2y)\\
 &= y \oplus 2(x \oplus 4x) = y \oplus (2x \oplus 8x)\\
 &= ( y \oplus 2x ) \oplus 8x = x \oplus 8x
\end{align}
$$
If we repeat this sort of argument, we find in general

$$\mathop{\large\oplus}_{k=0}^n 2^k y \stackrel{def}{=} ((\cdots (( y \oplus 2y ) \oplus 4y ) \cdots ) \oplus 2^n y) = x \oplus 2^{n+1} x$$

If the boolean algebra allow only finitely many digits. i.e.
there is a $N$ such that $2^{N+1} z = 0$ for all $z$, then $x$ has
following expression in terms of $y$:

$$x = \mathop{\large\oplus}_{k=0}^\infty 2^k y = \mathop{\large\oplus}_{k=0}^{N} 2^k y$$

**Update**

If we are dealing with $8$-bit unsigned integers, we can take $N = 7$ and 
$$x = y \oplus 2y \oplus 2^2y \oplus 2^3 y \oplus 2^4 y \oplus 2^5 y \oplus 2^6 y \oplus 2^7 y$$

In some programming like $C$, we can compute $x$ more effectively using constructs below

```
t  = y; 
t ^= t << 1;
t ^= t << 2;
t ^= t << 4;
x  = t & 0xff;
```